# Remove Query string to Post Form

Tags: html, forms, post, query-string

I have problems posting my form when there is a query string in the link.
After I submitted my form the first time, you can choose to submit again, this will redirect you to the same form as before with the script below:

```
<script>
 $(function() {
            $("#dialog").dialog({
         modal: true,
         resizable: false,
                 buttons: {
        "Yes":  function() {
                            var type = '<?php echo $type; ?>';
                            window.location.href="kit.php?type=<?php echo $type; ?>";
            },
        "No": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            }
            }
      });
     });
</script>
```

This is the form:

```
<form action="kitsubmit.php" method="post" name="complete">
```

This is the page of my form:

> localhost/Extracert/kit.php?type=AbELISA

After submit, i get redirected to this:

> localhost/Extracert/kit.php?type=AbELISA#/Extracert/kitsubmit.php

But should be be:

> localhost/Extracert/kitsubmit.php

I am new to this, so I don't know how to solve it...

Comment: There is no way to tell, from your question, why you are ending up on that URL. The form won't send you there. You might have JavaScript. There might be something on the server.

Comment: First I submit the form without a query string, what works fine, then on the next page, you can choose to submit again, this will redirect you to previous page, but with the query string, and then i get this problem

Comment: Why are you showing us code from a different page to the one causing the problem?

Comment: It's the same page, but with a query string at the end of the link.

Comment: You need to show us the code that is causing the problem.

Comment: I have no idea where to problem is, but I added the code(javascript) that i use to redirect to the form. If I redirect through this code, the form doesn't work anymore.. But it seems the query string isn't the problem.